# Restrict Player Movement to a Area of the Map Temporarily Unity Game Development C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

When my player gameObject collides with another gameObject, I want to keep the player from leaving a small area around this other gameObject until the player has defeated the enemy. In other words restrict the movement of the play until the enemy has been dealt with. I just don't know how to restrict the movement temporarily to a small amount of space local to where the initial collision took place.

I think possible solutions are to clamp the transform, or to create a another gameObject to physically keep the player in this area using rigidbody and a collider.

My player controlled movement right now is simply Input.GetAxis for both vertical and horizontal input and using transform.translate.

Thanks for reading my question. Any help would be appreciated, even something you might think is obvious, I'm still new to this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing any details about your game (2D,3D,etc.) my initial thought for doing something like this would be to spawn invisible wall gameObjects around your player and the enemy they collided with. Action games like Devil May Cry do this a lot, except they have pre-defined level spots where the walls are going to spawn.

When the player defeats the enemy, you could delete the walls.

Comment: This is how I deal with such requirements.

Comment: Thank you @Alex. I'm probably too new to try anything fancy anyways.

Comment: Would you use default gameObjects and just make them invisible and use code to have them spawn in a circle or whatever shape you desire?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would start with. You could also tell the invisible wall objects to ignore collisions from everything except the player + enemy, to allow for things like rockets/bullets to escape the area (it would look weird if they blew up seemingly for no reason on an invisible wall!). This would be accomplished with Unity's physics layers/filtering system, sorry I can't be more specific on that though because I haven't delved that far into Unity physics.